# Centering navbar links in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center my links on mobile view (md and down view) of my navbar but I can't seem to find a solution for it. **I am using bootstrap v4-alpha**

```
  <div class="container-fluid p-b-3">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-full  navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link pull-xs-right m-l-2 font-weight-bold" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="cursor:pointer;">LINK 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link pull-xs-right m-l-2 font-weight-bold" href="#kontakti">LINK 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link pull-xs-right m-l-2 font-weight-bold" href="#produktet">LINK 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>


</div>
```

[Here's the codepen link](http://codepen.io/Agonn/pen/dpbGBN)

Comment: You can just add some padding-right for the nav.

Comment: I don't think that would be responsive ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it using flexbox.

Here's a working pen I created: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwbpNx

CSS

```
.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I think this is one of the proper way to do it. So that, if you add another link. It will remain at center. Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use media query and override styles to make your links center aligned.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar ul {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  .navbar ul li a {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid p-b-3">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-full  navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link pull-xs-right m-l-2 font-weight-bold" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="cursor:pointer;">LINK 3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link pull-xs-right m-l-2 font-weight-bold" href="#kontakti">LINK 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link pull-xs-right m-l-2 font-weight-bold" href="#produktet">LINK 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```